# why the values of i and j are different with only one change in program

Tags: c++

program1:

```
#define MAX(x,y) (x)>(y)?(x):(y)
int main() 
{

    int i=10,j=5,k=0;
    k==MAX(i++,++j);
    cout<<i<<j<<k;
    return 0;
}
```

**o/p:11 7 0**

program 2:

```
#define MAX(x,y) (x)>(y)?(x):(y)
int main() 
{
    int i=10,j=5,k=0;
    k=MAX(i++,++j);
    cout<<i<<j<<k;
    return 0;
}
```

**o/p:12 6 11**

If you see above two programs carefully I'm only changing one line i.e `prog1.k==max()` as `prog2.k=max()` why this happening....?

Comment: Try to enable your compiler warning

Comment: Downvoters: note that the question is about why _`i` and `j`_ are different. The OP _knows_ the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: Looking at [operator precedence in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) should help you - In particular, notice that the ternary operator `?:` as lower precedence than the `==` operator.

Comment: First rule of writing macros: put parentheses around the body of any non-trivial macro. `#define MAX(x,y) ((x)>(y)?(x):(y))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first program, it will expand to

```
k==(i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(k == ((i++) > (++j))) ? (i++) : (++j)
```

Since the first `((i++) > (++j))` evaluates to `true`, then `(k == ((i++) > (++j)))` will evaluate to `false`, therefore only the second `(++j)` is evaluated.

The result: `(i++)` is evaluated once, `i` becomes `11`, `j` is evaluated twice, `j` becomes `7`. `k` isn't modified.

Compilers actually issue a warning about this behavior, see [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bd9e7dd56f02c13)

---

The second one is expanded to:

```
k=(i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j);
```

This is easy to understand, `i` will be `12`, `j` will be `6`, `k` is the result of `i++` before the second increment, which is `11`.

---

Anyway, please don't use macros in C++, except when you have no other choice.

Comment: Add insult to injury, isn't that operator getting undefined behavior if i is bigger that  j+1 (unknown if  assignment happens before or after the first post increment)?

Comment: @Swift there're no undefined behavior in any case. Ternary operator `?:` gives a sequence point at `?` the left side of `?`'s behavior is clear.

Answer (score 0):

After define, your code have been transformed like following

```
int main()
{

int i=10,j=5,k=0;
//(x)>(y)?(x):(y)
k == (i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j);
//i = 11, j = 7, k = 0

k = (i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j);
//i = 12,  j = 6, k = 11
cout<<i<<j<<k;
return 0;
}
```

**First case: program run orderly**

1. int temp = (k == i++); //Obviously the temp = 0, then i = 11
2. temp > (++j) ? (i++):(++j);

   //first, ++j. Then, j= 6 and check temp > 6? It's false, run ++j. so j = 7

Therefore, i = 11, j = 7, k didn't change.

**Second case: program run orderly**

1. (i++) > (++j)?

Because i = 10, j = 6, so this is true; (i++):(++j), we do former, i = 11.

2. Then, k = i; So, k = 11.
3. After above statement, i = 12 because ++i;

   Therefore, i = 12, j = 6, k = 11

Answer (score -1):

You should know the difference between `= and ==` , = is assignment operator and == is comparison operator, in the first case k=0, because you are not assigning anything in k, the other values are different i don't know how you are running this programs, run it individually it should be same

Answer (score -2):

Program1 you have

```
k==MAX(i++,++j); // notice 2 equal signs
```

program2 you have

```
k=MAX(i++,++j); // 1 equal sign.
```